Sharing Rules is not working

i have requirement to gived edit access to Case records of recordtype Mortgage support case to the case edit group. following is the criteria based sharing rule, i have giver read/write access.
when i login as the group user and check for access i am not getting any access.
NOTE :OWD settings are set private and user does not have any access to case object at profile level.

The user who you are logging in as needs to have at least Read on Case in order to see the object that the sharing rule applies to.
Permissions determine what objects/fields the user has access to.
Sharing determines what specific records within the constraints of their Permission access the user can see.

my requiremnt is user added to particular group and permission set should  have read/ @jeff clark write access for mortgage recordtype and only read access for Pin chnage recordtype.if i give read/ write access to user at permssion set and implement only read access to pin change recordtype in sharing rule , user is getting read/ write access.and what purpose does recordtype selection provide in permission sets.and How do i achive my requirement?

To achieve what you're looking for, Read/Write is required for the object level. Record Type assignments on the profile/permission set really only allow for the ability to create records with that Record Type.
Visibility of the records will all be determined by the sharing settings.
